# Flex TextArea Keep focus/selection when a button is clicked

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am wondering how I would keep the focus/selection on a TextArea even when a button outside is clicked.

Like how the RichTextEditor does it.

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler for the click event you will want to stopImmediatePropagation() and preventDefault() and then do your business with the selection/focus.

Comment: Hi Joel. That didnt work, on the buttons click event I used those two events and the button still stole the focus from the TextArea.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `RichTextEditor` is accomplishing its maintaining focus with the following line in `setTextStyles()`:

```
callLater(textArea.setFocus)
```

I think any user interaction with the `RTE`'s controls will lead through this method, so that returns focus after the control event has completed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a simple text box. I have a button that pulls the highlighted value and ajax sends it to the server. But when the focus is taken off of the button it the highlight value `window.getSelection().toString()` is blank.

I was able to solve this by simply setting the focus back to the the text area. Cheap solution I know but it works. I use jQuery but it probably won't be difficult to come up with a vanilla javascript version.

```
$holder.on('click', '.name-add_option input', function(e)
{
  // Make sure the button doesn't do something silly like submit the form.
  e.preventDefault();

  // Set the focus to the text area I expect the highlighted text to be.
  $holder.find('.name-field textarea').focus();

  // Copy highlighted text.
  highlight = window.getSelection().toString();

  // Do stuff with highlighted data.
});
```

`$holder` is a jquery handle of a div styled as a modal window in my context.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical">
    <mx:TextArea id="textArea" focusOut="{textArea.setFocus()}" />
    <mx:Button id="test" label="Test" />
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: This sort of works. But when I select between two of the TextArea there is a overflow exception, prob because both are trying to take the focus.

Comment: Maybe something like this but it only uses setFocus if the next focus is the certain button. I might try that.